# Cannot change ListView in TabHost in Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-tabhost

This is my Java code for making TabHost Widget and showing news list.
But when I clicked widget Tab, listview doesn't change. I have four tabs, but all show same listview(lv).

I want to know how to change ListView section (Frame section).
what can I type in setOnTabChangedListener? or do I have to use another way?

I add my JAVA code and XML code.

**XML CODE :**

```xml
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="SPEAK"
        android:gravity="center">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="STOP"
        android:gravity="center">
    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**JAVA CODE :**

```java
package com.scsa.project.news;

import java.util.Locale;
import com.scsa.project.R;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class NewsActivity extends Activity implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private INewsDAO mgr = new NewsNetDAOImpl();
    private ArrayAdapter<News> adapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<News> adapter2;
    private ArrayAdapter<News> adapter3;
    private ArrayAdapter<News> adapter4;
    ListView lv;
    ListView lv2;
    ListView lv3;
    ListView lv4;
    TextToSpeech myTTS;
    Button start;
    Button stop;

    //TabHost
    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<News>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mgr.getNewsList("http://myhome.chosun.com/rss/www_section_rss.xml"));
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<News>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mgr.getNewsList("http://rss.joins.com/joins_homenews_list.xml"));
        adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<News>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mgr.getNewsList("http://rss.donga.com/total.xml"));
        adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<News>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mgr.getNewsList("http://rss.etnews.com/Section901.xml"));

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        this.registerForContextMenu(lv);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);     
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object item = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String title = item.toString();
                String url = mgr.getLink(title);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
            }
        });

        lv2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv2);
        lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object item = lv2.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String title = item.toString();
                String url = mgr.getLink(title);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
            }
        });

        lv3 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv3);
        lv3.setAdapter(adapter3);
        lv3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object item = lv3.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String title = item.toString();
                String url = mgr.getLink(title);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
            }
        });

        lv4 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv4);
        lv4.setAdapter(adapter4);
        lv4.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object item = lv4.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String title = item.toString();
                String url = mgr.getLink(title);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
            }
        });

        //TabHost 
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First");
        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second");
        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third");
        TabSpec tab4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth");

        tab1.setIndicator("CHOSUN").setContent(R.id.lv);
        tab2.setIndicator("JOONGANG").setContent(R.id.lv2);
        tab3.setIndicator("DONGA").setContent(R.id.lv3);    
        tab4.setIndicator("ETNEWS").setContent(R.id.lv4);
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);
        tabHost.addTab(tab4);

        //TabHost 

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(NewsActivity.this, NewsActivity.this);
            }
        });

        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myTTS.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                if(tabId.equals("First")) {
                }else if(tabId.equals("Second")) {
                }else if(tabId.equals("Third")) {
                }else if(tabId.equals("Fourth")) {
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTTS.shutdown();
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.KOREAN);
            for(int i=0; i<mgr.size(); i++) {
                myTTS.speak(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```